# Get unknown args after multiple parse_known_args calls

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to get the unparsed args after multiple `argparse.parse_known_args()` calls?

For example, I've got the following code:

```
import argparse, sys

def parse1():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--foo", action="store_true")
  args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]
  print("foo: ", args.foo)

def parse2():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--bar", action="store_true")
  args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
  print("bar: ", args.bar)
  print("unknown: ", unknown)

sys.argv += ["--foo", "--bar", "--last"]
parse1()
parse2()

"""
Outputs: 

foo:  True
bar:  True
unknown:  ['--foo', '--last']
"""
```

I wish to somehow get the unknown vars of only `'--last'`, which was not parsed in `parse1()` or `parse2()`

Any ideas how?

Comment: Maybe you should only pass the so-far-unknown args to the next parser? The other thing that came to mind is a set intersection, but that could be problematic where order matters.

Comment: although it works around the immediate problem, parse1 and parse2 are in different parts of the code and passing a list of yet-to-be-parsed args between them should be avoided if possible, since I wish the parts to stay decoupled

Comment: both parsers read the same `argv`.  You have to modify `sys.argv` yourself if you want something different.

Comment: You're coupling them at one end or the other, because what you want _is_ a combination. If each of your parse functions took the argument list and returned the args namespace and unknown, which also makes them easier to test, then you could either pass them both the same thing and diff the return values, or pass one's unknown as inputs to the next.

Comment: Another way to put this - a parse_known_args` call does not change the `sys.argv`.  You have to some how pass the `extras` from one call to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

```
def pop_unknown_args(parser: ArgumentParser) -> Namespace:
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + unknown
    return args
```

hpaulj, thanks for the comment